# Splicing strings in C#

Tags: python, c#

How do you splice strings in C#? how would i translate the following python code into C#?

```
string = "this is a string"

string[-1]          ## last letter
string[:2]           ## first 2 letters
string[2:]           ## letters after 2nd letter
string[-2]            ## last 2 letters

words = string.split()    ## list of words 
## ["this","is","a","string"]
string_again = " ".join(words)  ## list of words back to 
## string
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried. SO is not a code translation service

Comment: First of all, you can't use the variable name 'string' in C#. It's protected.

Comment: Some of the answers are made obvious by simply inspecting `System.String`. For the rest, take a look at the extension methods provided by `System.Linq.Enumerable`. You won't get the compact syntax Python offers though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I appreciate that cross-langing is hard because some things just aren't easy to google for. Try looking for a "Python to C# cheatsheet"

```
//py
string = "this is a string"
//c#
string myStringName = "this is a string";
var myStringName = "this is a string";
String myStringName = "this is a string"

//py
string[-1]          ## last letter
//c#
char c = myStringName[myStringName.Length-1];

//py
string[:2]           ## first 2 letters
//c#
string firstTwo = myStringName.Remove(2);

//py
string[2:]           ## letters after 2nd letter
//c#
string remainder = myStringName.Substring(2);

//py
string[-2]            ## last 2 letters
//c#
string lastTwo = myStringName.Substring(mystringName.Length - 2);

//py
words = string.split()    ## list of words 
//c#
myStringName = "this,is,a,string";
string[] strArray = myStringName.Split(',');

//py
string_again = "".join(words)  ## list of words back to 
//c#
string stringWithCommasAgain = string.Join(",", strArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

C# 8 now provides ["indices and ranges"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) with syntax similar in conciseness as Python's slice notation.

```
string myString = "this is a string";

myString[^1]         // last letter
myString[..2]        // first 2 letters
myString[2..]        // letters after 2nd letter
myString[^2]         // second to last letter 
myString[^2..]       // last 2 letters

var words = myString.Split();                // list of words 
var string_again = string.Join(" ", words);  // list of words back to string
```